# Qt for Symbian books

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

I want to start developing apps for my new Nokia E7-00.

What book do you recommend me?

I've read [Beginning Nokia Apps Development: Qt and HTML5 for Symbian and MeeGo (Books for Professionals by Professionals)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1430231777/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d3_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1K718XZP00247EKYC61C&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294) and I need more!!

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [Qt for Symbian](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470750103.html), a book by Frank H. P. Fitzek & Co.